# How to update state for function that relies on if statement from state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array called values:

```
values = RAW_VALUES.map((data) => {
  return {
    id: data.id,
    name: data.name,
    value: financials[data.id],
    add: false,
    subtract: false,
    change: "",
    newValue: "",
  };
});
```

and a function:

```
  updateValues(val, index) {
    let { values } = this.state;

    if (!isNaN(val)) {
      values[index].change = parseFloat(val);
      if(values[index].add){ //this checks if add property is true
        values[index].newValue = values[index].value + values[index].change
      }
      this.setState({
        values,
      });
    }
  }
```

I have a button called 'Add' which toggles the `add` field of each index in `values`.

To update `values[index].newValue`, the user currently needs to set `add` to true first and then type in the updated value.

How can I ensure that the value is also updated if the user first types in the value, and then sets `add` to true ?

This is how updateValues is called in render:

```
                  <MetricInput
                    value={values[index]?.change}
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      this.updateValues(e.target.value, index) //function
                    }
                  />
```

Edit: There are two buttons, `add` and `subtract`. if `add` is set to true then I'd want to do `values[index].newValue = values[index].value + values[index].change`
Else, if `subtract` is set to true, I'd do `values[index].newValue = values[index].value - values[index].change`

Answer (score 0):

Not withstanding there are better ways to update an array of objects, can you not consider ignoring the `if(values[index].add)` condition and just set `values[index].add = true` ?

```
updateValues(val, index) {
    let { values } = this.state;

    if (!isNaN(val)) {
      values[index].change = parseFloat(val);
        values[index].newValue = values[index].value + values[index].change
        values[index].add = true
      this.setState({
        values,
      });
    }
  }
```

Update - Keep the above, and consider making numbers Positive or Negative depending on Add/Subtract

const onAdd = (index) => {
let values = this.state.values;
values[index].newValue = Math.abs(values[index].newValue)
this.setState({ values })
}

const onSubtract = (index) => {
let values = this.state.values;
values[index].newValue = -Math.abs(values[index].newValue)
this.setState({ values })
}

Comment: Nope, it needs to be an if-else because if `subtract` is true, then I'd do `values[index].value - values[index].change` instead

Comment: how about `if (!values[index].subtract)` ?

Comment: I'm not sure how that will solve it. I've updated my question with more information though

Comment: I see what you mean now, if I set it to `(!values[index].subtract)`, then even if the user unclicks the add to make it false, it would still go into the if statement which is not what we want.

Comment: Well, then you are contradicting your own logic, which you may want to reconsider. E.g. What is a change? What is add? What is subtract? Should you disable the field unless the user click add/subtract? Are the values numeric? Adding positive or negative works as well.

Comment: I've added a suggested updated, to make newValue positive or negative depending on whether you click on add/subtract, which I feel is a better pattern.